# Clarification regarding substitution in sequent calculus

Tags: logic, quantifiers, proof-theory, formal-proofs, sequent-calculus

Wikipedia's [Sequent Calculus article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Inference_rules) states:

> $A[t/x]$ denotes the formula that is obtained by substituting the term $t$ for every free occurrence of the variable $x$ in formula $A$ with the restriction that the term $t$ must be free for the variable $x$ in $A$ (i.e., **no occurrence of any variable in $t$ becomes bound in $A[t/x]$**).

Is the bolded text slightly wrong/confusing? Shouldn't it be:

> (i.e., no occurrence of any **free** variable in $t$ becomes bound in $A[t/x]$)

since $A$ may have bounded variables already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original bold text is correct. Indeed, $t$ is a term, not a formula, and so *no* quantifiers or any other kind of binders can occur in it, hence *every* variable occurring in $t$ is *free* (in $t$) by necessity. Actually, your version of the bold text (which adds "free") is not wrong, but only superfluous: adding "free" does not change anything in the restriction.

The point is that when you substitute $t$ for every free occurrence of $x$ in $A$, some variables in $t$ (which are free in $t$ by necessity, as said above) can become bound in $A[t/x]$ (because of some quantifiers in $A$), and this is what must be avoided.

---

More generally, the notion of "being free" is not absolute, but is always relative to a context where variables appear. The free variables of a formula $A$ are the variables that occur free *in* $A$, i.e. that are not bound by any binders in $A$. The free variables of a term $t$ are the variables that are free *in* $t$, i.e. that are not bound by any  binders in $t$ (which is always the case because there are no binders in a term in first-order logic).

Comment: @Taroccoesbroco thanks for the clarification. I asked a related question which might interest you: [Substitution in Sequent Calculus vs Substitution in lambda Calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4312620/substitution-in-sequent-calculus-vs-substitution-in-lambda-calculus).

Comment: Can a term $t$ have no variables?

Comment: @joseville - Yes, for instance a constant symbol $c$ is a term without variables. If the language of first-order logic is without constant symbols, every term contains at least one variable.